# Access and webscrape dynamic pages using python

Tags: python, dynamic, web-scraping, web-crawler, http-post

I am trying to access a web page using it's form parameters.
I found the form parameters using Network headers in chrome's developer tab.
But it's not working, instead it's  just opening the page before these parameters are used (i.e [www.irishancestors.ie/search/townlands/ded_index.php](http://www.irishancestors.ie/search/townlands/ded_index.php))

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open('http://www.irishancestors.ie/search/townlands/ded_index.php?action=listp&parish=Aghagallon')
```

My intention is to retrieve all the tables of each District Electoral Division of all the counties.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

webbrowser doesn't do what you think it does.

If you want to get/post data to a webpage, you should use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/)

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events')
>>> r = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', data = {'key':'value'})
```

`webbrowser` is for launching your web browser.

Note that this won't work very well if there's a bunch of javascript in use (well, it might, but it requires a lot more work on your part). If you have a lot of Javascript, it may be easier to use [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)